# Items being checked out to me, the sharepoint developer

Tags: 2010, designer-workflow, check-out, check-in, impersonation

Hello again and thanks for taking the time to look at my issue.

I've got a site that I've just taken ownership of and I'm tracking a major workflow bug that is disrupting my users' ability to work. We've got a tracker document, acting as an info path form, that is the central point for actions taken on these list items. When you push an item to the next point in the user process, a workflow reads the changed status, updates permissions, and moves on with its day. Unfortunately since yesterday it has started checking out the items in my name. Now I know I run particular steps under "Impersonation Steps", so I get that I'm authoring a modification to the file, however up until now it has never checked out the items to the workflow author, only since I've made changes.

**At what stage(s) are you meant to check in/check out an item in a workflow. The current workflow doesn't bother to explicitly check the item out, should it be checked out to me at all?**

I apologize if this question is a bit vague, it's more of a conceptual question than looking for a fix. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Miguet,
do you know if version settings has been updated for your form library.  Verify if you have accidentally updated the version setting and selected "Require Checkout" option.

What kind of workflow are we talking about (SharePoint Designer, Visual Studio)?

Comment: Thanks for your response Sudhir. Looking at the versioning settings for the library, require checkout is set to "No". The workflow was built and published from SharePoint Designer 2010

Comment: What has changed since it started checking out items with your name.

Comment: If your workflow is making some changes to the form,  i would suggest to include a checkout activity and corresponding check-in activity in your workflow.

Comment: Understood Sudhir, I think that is the root of my question; is this done as an impersonation step at the beginning and end of the workflow? Or should this be performed at the individual step level (my assumption is the former option). The only change I've made is adding an email alert to a delete function.

Comment: yes,  you are right,  Add checkout as the first step in your Workflow,  and check-in as last activity.

Comment: Thanks I'll make those changes now. Appreciate the help! I wish I could upvote you but my rep is still too low.